# Netbeans - Missing Debug section in Project Properties => Cannot debug JavaScript

Tags: javascript, debugging, jsp, netbeans

I'm trying to debug some Javascript code inside a JSP page in a web app (Servlets, JSP and JavaScript) I'm working on. In order to be able to debug it I understand I need to check the **Debug Web Application (Client side JavaScript)** option under **Debug** section in the **Project Properties** window.

The problem is I don't have any Debug section in the Project Properties window. I also don't have the **JavaScript Libraries** section, but I'm not sure whether it's related or not.

What I'm looking for is what is shown [here](http://netbeans.org/kb/67/web/js-debugger-ug.html#enable).

Just to be clear, what I need is to be able to debug JavaScript, so if there's a different solution for doing this I would be more than happy to here about it.

If its worth anything I **can** put breakpoints inside JavaScript, its just that I cannot see any values of variables.

Thanks,

Alon

***[EDIT:] As ladar kindly pointed out, the JavaScript debugger was dropped from Netbeans in previous versions ([It seems like in version 6.9](http://forums.netbeans.org/topic28527.html)). As an alternative I use Firebug now.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of NetBeans are you using? Javascript debugger was dropped in recent versions (as far as I know 7.0 and newer doesn't support it). So because there is no js debugger, this screenshot is not there because it will always debug server side code

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Netbeans 7.01 (latest stable), so I guess I was referring to an outdated article. I guess I'll just use firebug instead.